# Trying to get Facebook Emitter working

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eventemitter

I get the following error when trying Facebook emitter from node command line. I tried removing {} around `EventEmitter` without Bable, then with Bable and the code below.

[EventEmitter](https://github.com/facebook/emitter)

Setup, as per: [Using Babel. How to use Babel with your tool of choice](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)

```
npm install fbemitter
npm install babel-register
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc
```

Node error:

> ```
> $ node emit-node.js
> /Users/carlf/Documents/dev/test/emitter/emit-node.js:3
> var {EventEmitter} = require('./node_modules/emitter');
>     ^
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
> ```

My code:

```
require("babel-register");

var {EventEmitter} = require('./node_modules/emitter');
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.addListener('event', function(x, y) { console.log(x, y); });
emitter.emit('event', 5, 10);  // Listener prints "5 10".
```

FILE: `.bablerc`

```
{ "presets": ["es2015"] }
```

Comment: your babel setup doesn't understand destructuring

Comment: IIRC, you have to load `babel-register` *before* requiring the first module that uses ES6 syntax

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing, `require("babel-register");` comes before `var {EventEmitter} = require('./node_modules/emitter');`

Comment: @Bergi Please see: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/ and my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To include it you will need to require it at the top of the **entry** point to your application.

If you use babel-register, it won't apply the transforms on the file that calls `require("babel-register");` itself. Thus you would need to move that call to a separate file and then call the es2015 code.

```
// file1.js
require("babel-register");
require('./file2.js');

// file2.js
// other code
```

It probably could be more clear - maybe even and example like I posted above. Feel free to send a PR or I'l fix something up later.